# Proving the existence of a subgroup of specified order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was given the following question on a midterm practice which has no solutions on it. I am stuck and I am wondering if there isn't a typo in the problem.

*Let G be an abelian group of order n and d be an integer dividing n. Prove that G has a subgroup of order d and a quotient group of order d.*

My first thought is that there is a typo and the group is supposed to be cyclic. However, if that isn't the case, I have really no idea how to proceed. I thought I could define some sort of group homomorphism on G with kernel of size n/d and then apply the first isomorphism thereom, but I'm unable to come up with a suitable homomorphism since there is no more information.

Am I correct thinking this is a typo, or am I just not making a connection?

Comment: It is not a typo.

Comment: Okay, thank you-I'll keep at it then.

Comment: As said, it is not a typo. There are a couple of ways to show this. The easiest is probably by induction on the order of the group (consider any proper non-trivial quotient).